# how to make a textbox and/or a listbox disappear when not needed in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

For my midterm in Visual Basic .NET i need to show my proficiency in using various common controls, and this includes a listbox and a textbox w/ 2 buttons as an output. Basically i need the textbox with the two buttons to disappear when i am using the listbox as an output and vice versa.
image :
code:

```
Public Class Form1


  Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    'Dim total As Integer
    'Dim numone As Integer
    'Dim numtwo As Integer
    '
    'numone = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    'numtwo = Val(TextBox3.Text)
    'total = numone + numtwo
    '
    'TextBox5.Text = total

  End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    'Dim total As Integer
    'Dim numone As Integer
    'Dim numtwo As Integer
    '
    'numone = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    'numtwo = Val(TextBox3.Text)
    'total = numone - numtwo
    '
    'TextBox5.Text = total
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
    'Dim total As Integer
    'Dim numone As Integer
    'Dim numtwo As Integer
    '
    'numone = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    'numtwo = Val(TextBox3.Text)
    'total = numone / numtwo

    'TextBox5.Text = total
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox4_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox4.CheckedChanged
    'Dim total As Integer
    'Dim numone As Integer
    'Dim numtwo As Integer
    '
    'numone = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    'numtwo = Val(TextBox3.Text)
    'total = numone * numtwo
    '
    'TextBox5.Text = total
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox5_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox5.CheckedChanged
    'Dim FirstName As String
    'Dim LastName As String
    'Dim WholeName As String
    '
    'FirstName = TextBox2.Text
    'LastName = TextBox4.Text
    '
    ' WholeName = FirstName & " " & LastName
    '
    'TextBox5.Text = WholeName

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox7_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox7.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox7.CheckState = 1 Then
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Homer Simpson")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Marge Simpson")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Bart Simpson")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Lisa Simpson")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Maggie Simpson")

        'TextBox5.Text = Val(ComboBox1)


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If CheckBox1.CheckState = 1 Then
        Dim total As Integer
        Dim numone As Integer
        Dim numtwo As Integer

        numone = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        numtwo = Val(TextBox3.Text)
        total = numone + numtwo

        TextBox5.Text = total


    End If
    If CheckBox2.CheckState = 1 Then
        Dim total As Integer
        Dim numone As Integer
        Dim numtwo As Integer

        numone = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        numtwo = Val(TextBox3.Text)
        total = numone - numtwo

        TextBox5.Text = total


    End If
    If CheckBox3.CheckState = 1 Then
        Dim total As Integer
        Dim numone As Integer
        Dim numtwo As Integer

        numone = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        numtwo = Val(TextBox3.Text)
        numone = total / numtwo

        TextBox5.Text = total



    End If
    If CheckBox4.CheckState = 1 Then
        Dim total As Integer
        Dim numone As Integer
        Dim numtwo As Integer

        numone = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        numtwo = Val(TextBox3.Text)
        total = numone * numtwo

        TextBox5.Text = total


    End If
    If CheckBox5.CheckState = 1 Then
        Dim FirstName As String
        Dim LastName As String
        Dim WholeName As String

        FirstName = TextBox2.Text
        LastName = TextBox4.Text

        WholeName = FirstName & " " & LastName

        TextBox5.Text = WholeName


    End If
    If CheckBox6.CheckState = 1 Then

        With ListBox1
            .Enabled = True 'if the listox is enable or disabled
            .Sorted = True ' if you want ti list sorted
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D ' the border style
            .Visible = True
            .ScrollAlwaysVisible = True 'presence of scroll all time
            .MultiColumn = False 'add a new column if number of items reach max height
        End With

        ListBox1.Items.Add("Homer Simpson")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Marge Simpson")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Bart Simpson")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Lisa Simpson")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Maggie Simpson")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo1")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo2")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo3")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo4")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo5")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo1")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo2")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo3")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo4")
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("allo5")
    End If

    If CheckBox7.CheckState = 1 Then
        'ComboBox1.Items.Add("Homer Simpson")
        'ComboBox1.Items.Add("Marge Simpson")
        'ComboBox1.Items.Add("Bart Simpson")
        'ComboBox1.Items.Add("Lisa Simpson")
        'ComboBox1.Items.Add("Maggie Simpson")

        TextBox5.Text = ComboBox1.Text


    End If

End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox5.Clear()

End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    ' text2.Clear()
    ' text1.Clear()
    ' text2.Clear()

    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    CheckBox1.Checked = False
    CheckBox2.Checked = False
    CheckBox3.Checked = False
    CheckBox4.Checked = False
    CheckBox5.Checked = False
    CheckBox6.Checked = False
    CheckBox7.Checked = False

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to hide the Listbox if you type something in the Textbox? Then handle the `.TextChanged` event of the Textbox and to a `Listbox1.Visible=False` into the handler. You probably mean something different but it's not clear from your question. Please explain a bit more what you want to achieve and post more relevant code excerpts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ListBox as output add for WinForms

```
ListBox1.Visible=True 'make sure user can see output
TextBox1.Visible=False
Button1.Visible=False 'textbox button
Button2.Visible=False 'textbox button
```

or for WPF

```
ListBox1.Visibility=Visibility.Visible 'make sure user can see output
TextBox1.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden
Button1.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden 'textbox button
Button2.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden 'textbox button
```

Use similar code if you use TextBox as output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand what you are trying to do but the codes for making the `listbox` and `button` disappear are:

```
ListBox1.visible = false
Button1.visible = false
```

then when you want them to appear again:

```
ListBox1.visible = true
Button1.visible = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDown
    Me.ListBox1.visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown
    Me.TextBox1.Visible = False
    Me.Button1.Visible = False
    Me.Button2.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Just add these two subs and what you want should work properly.